# web api http post passing object 504 Receive Failure

Tags: http, asp.net-web-api, http-post

debugging on my local machine. I have fidder simulate requests to http post web api `http://localhost:15147/api/Pacel/CreatePacel/`

if I set fidder "Composer"--"Request Headers" to:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Accepted: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 0
Host: localhost:15147
```

it did work and i am confirmed it can go into my breakpoint at “`if (pacel == null)  // SET BREAKPOINT HERE`”

but if i set `Content-Length: 1000` and add "Request Body" in fidder "Composer" as:

```
{
   "id": 3
   "province":"US",
   "city":"US"
}
```

it does not go into the breakpoint “`if (pacel == null)  // SET BREAKPOINT HERE`”

could anybody know what is the problem?

action method in PacelContrller is in below:

```
// POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("CreatePacel")]
        public HttpResponseMessage CreatePacel([FromBody]Pacel pacel)
        {
            try
            {
                if (pacel == null)  // SET BREAKPOINT HERE
                {
                    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "can not read object from body.");
                }
                else
                {
                    int effectedRows = 0;
                    effectedRows = pr.Add(pacel);
                    if (effectedRows == 0)
                    {
                        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "can not save to the db.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, "created items in db success.");
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
            }


        }
```

Pacel Model is below:

```
public partial class Pacel
    {
        public long pacelId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> arrivedDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> signDate { get; set; }
        public string signname { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> customerId { get; set; }
        public string province { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string district { get; set; }
        public string campname { get; set; }
        public string bldNumber { get; set; }
        public string unitNumber { get; set; }
        public string roomNumber { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }
```

***EDIT after @Rafa answer***

with body { "pacelId": 3 "province":"US", "city":"US" } and leave content length = 0; it can work well(means it can go into the breakpoint). but the object cannot be passed in the serverside. at the breakpoint, it shows `pacel` is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request body is badly formed, you need to add a comma after the first property (id). I would also change "id" to pacelId to match your pacel object:

```
{
   "pacelId": 3,
   "province":"US",
   "city":"US"
}
```

Note: you can get Fiddler to set the Content-Length automatically:

Composer > Options tab and check the "Fix Content-Length header" option.

Comment: Composer > Options tab and check the "Fix Content-Length header" option.  This works for me. thnx

Answer (score 0):

I think the JSON that you're sending doesn't fit the model, you may try with:

{
   "pacelId": 3
   "province":"US",
   "city":"US"
}

I would leave at first the content length = 0 or put the real content length.

Comment: leave content length = 0; it can work well. but the object cannot be passed in. at the breakpoint, it shows pacel is null.

Comment: in this case, it is problem with the serialization and matching of the JSON object. Try to enhance it with more fields.

Comment: still get null when passing in body { "pacelId": 3, "arrivedDate":"2014-02-25", "signDate":"2014-02-25", "signname":"max","customerId":1, "province":"US", "city":"US", "district":"US", "campname":"US","bldNumber":"3", "unitNumber":"3", "roomNumber":"1504", "type": "0" } , any idea?

Comment: check your configuration (web.config) to be sure that your web service accepts JSON

Comment: r u sure json can be set in web.config?

Comment: no, I'm not, but depending on the framework that you're using, there must be a file or property where you can set that your web service accepts JSON. In some frameworks, this option will tell the deserializer how to deserialize.